# What is best way to iterate millions of records in angular or type script

Tags: angular, typescript

Need to load multiple multi select drop-down with cascading effect that are related.

I have millions of records coming from API that are duplicate in some column but unique if we consider all columns.

Need to fill 10-12 multi-select drop-down with API data. And In on-change event of drop-down I need to apply cascading effect by iterating millions of records.

What is best way to solve this kind of problem.

Comment: Millions? Each drop down has 100,000 potential options?

Comment: Hi, sorry for asking but: Dropdowns with "millions" of options are kinda useless in realworld... Is this what you really wanna do ?

Answer (score 1):

you shouldn't do this on the frontend side it's impossible to be efficient.

- retrieval of millions of records by one API call will be very slow
- Loading all this data in one page will make the page very slow and use much memory. and you won't be able to do operations on it.

So it's needed to be changed from the API side to use pagination or to query only the needed part of data on change by sending a new API request